# Running pgadmin4 in debian12

Tags: pgadmin-4

Can someone assist me in resolving the following issue? When I run the command "apt update" in the Shell, I receive the following message: "W: GPG error: https://nightly.odoo.com/17.0/nightly/deb ./ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DEF2A2198183CBB5."